# How to Grab input values of dynamically added input boxes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to add dynamic fields on click and want to fetch each input box value that user types. Here is my working code.
HTML code

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
 <div><input type="text" name="mytext"> <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
</div>
</div>
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
   var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><tr><td><input type="text" name="textbox' + x + '" id="removeId' + x + '" value="' + x + '" ></td><td><button class="remove_field" >Remove</button><button class="save_field" >save</button></td></tr></div>'); //add input box

        }
    });
 $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
        x--;
    })
    $(wrapper).on("click",".save_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); 
        //Here on click of each save button I wanna grab particular text box value that user types in
})
});
```

On each click of add more fields I get new text box along with remove and save button, upon clicking on save button I want to grab its respective text box value that user has typed.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tbdtq7Ld/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clicked button is sibling of required input tag. you can use `.siblings('input')` or `.prevAll('input')` to target input element along with `.val()` to get its value:

```
$(this).siblings('input').val();
```

**Handler:**

```
$(wrapper).on("click",".save_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); 
    alert($(this).siblings('input').val());
    //Here on click of each save button I wanna grab particular text box value that user types in
});
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 1):

PFB code , hope it helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><tr><td><input type="text" name="textbox' + x + '" id="removeId' + x + '" value="' + x + '" ></td><td><button class="remove_field" >Remove</button><button class="save_field" >save</button></td></tr></div>'); //add input box

    }
  });
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".save_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    var inpVal = $(this).siblings('input').val();
    alert('inp value is :' + inpVal);
    e.preventDefault();
    //Here on click of each save button I wanna grab particular text box value that user types in
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="mytext">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give dynamic id to your textboxes replace:

```
id="removeId'
```

with

```
id="removeId'+k
```

And then you can access them using

```
$("#id").val();
```